# How to make some text between two lines?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have some text and a line.

I need to make the picture look like this:
[image]

In my HTML code it looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="line"></div> 
        <h2>Some Text!!!</h2>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    text-align: center; 
}

.line {
    height: 5px;
    background: #FFEE90;
}
```

What should I write to place my text between the lines?

Comment: I've seen this has been asked at least 2 times in here (since March 2014, not sure about the time before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (using one line and relative position on h2 element):

jsfiddle.net/td8L8/

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this with several ways.

You could add content line with before and after pseudo elements

```
p:before {
    content: "_____";
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -45px;
}

p:after {
    content: "_____";
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -45px;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/82EvC/

Another way could be with border lines

```
p:before {
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 8px;
    left: -45px;
}

p:after {
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: -45px;
}
```

an example: http://jsfiddle.net/82EvC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Full width line and some html.

[DEMO](http://cdpn.io/yHJIu)

```
<div class="line"><span>Some text</span></div>


.line {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.line:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.line span {
  padding: 0 8px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```